# Rotating 2d rectangle around central point returns only two correct points! Why?

Tags: python, rotation, 2d, point

I have 4 coordinates in wgs84:

```
north=39.92911484169648
south=39.88787873513176
east=16.60177886077772
west=16.57366683077252
```

By combining them, I can get the shape of a rectangle (NW, NE, SW, SE) and the the center of the above rectangle

```
39.90849678841412 16.587723359360467
```

I followed several answers here on stackoverflow to translate the rectangle to zero, rotate the points by 70 degrees counterclockwise around the center, and then translate back to original coordinates (all in python).

```
def rotate(origin, point, angle):
    """
    Rotate a point counterclockwise by a given angle around a given origin.

    The angle should be given in radians.
    """
    ox, oy = origin
    px, py = point

    qx = ox + cos(angle) * (px - ox) - sin(angle) * (py - oy)
    qy = oy + sin(angle) * (px - ox) + cos(angle) * (py - oy)

    return qx, qy
```

When I print back the rotated points, for some reason I get correctly ONLY the NE and SW. I cannot understand the reason for that. I attach an image to make it clearer, where the white rectangle is made with the initial values, the red is made with rotated coordinate while the green is the expected result.

Printout of results=white: initial; red: rotated with above code; green: expected

[image: Printout of results=white: initial; red: rotated with above code; green: expected]

Can you help me understand why and perhaps suggest a solution or point out where my error is?

Thanks a lot

Comment: what is the reason for `degrees(qx)`

Comment: because numbers have been previously converted in radians

Comment: why convert the lat-lon coords to radians? So the input of rotate are coordinates in radians and the result is in degrees, this will result in a lot of confusion/errors

Comment: I see. I remember I've seen it somewhere. Nevermind, I removed it now and I get the exact same results

Comment: are you feeding the rotate method the correct coordinates, the incorrect points have matching values of other correct points

Comment: This is what I pass `print(rotate((center4326y,center4326x),(north,east),(-70.64234161376955)))
print(rotate((center4326y,center4326x),(north,west),(-70.64234161376955)))
print(rotate((center4326y,center4326x),(south,east),(-70.64234161376955)))
print(rotate((center4326y,center4326x),(south,west),(-70.64234161376955)))`

Comment: then why do you unpack it with `ox,oy` and you return `qx,qy`, why is the angle in parenthesis

Comment: You are right, the code needs some fixing (basically I adapted it from another script and I didn't bother to change it completely) but both the unpacking and the parenthesis -although annoying- do not affect the result

Comment: you set the argument as `(y,x)` and you unpack as `x,y`

Comment: My mistake with naming (center4326y is actually the x and center4326x is the y). If they were the wrong way I would have get completely different values (-5.68208472379542, 15.575817017589845 instead of 39.92343545808347, 16.56773592856622)

Comment: `north,east` is `y,x`, you translate to the origin - rotate - then translate back so the rectangle is still centered at the same spot

Comment: so you find out your code contains confusing variable names and errors and still don't fix them, WHY

Comment: correct, but even changing the values with the correct order as you suggest (y,x for north east), the result does not change a lot

Comment: I will correct them. But if you try yourself with correct values you will see that result does not change much and I still get points far from where I expect them to be.

Comment: I have fixed the coord confusion and made a turtle animation for multiple angles and it works

Comment: do you mind sharing your code or more details on your approach?

Comment: I really cannot get it. I fixed all naming and values, but I am not able to get good results. @rioV8 can you please help me since you managed to do it? Thanks